# Is the code within #define macro added in the build?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have certain lines of code within a macro

```
//#define EnablePushNotification

#ifdef EnablePushNotification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
#endif
```

My question is "whether the .ipa file generated will contain the code inside "EnablePushNotification", if the "EnablePushNotification" is commented out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are processed [before](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Phases) the preprocessor kicks in, so no it will not.

Comment: Whether the code within the #ifdef EnablePushNotification will be added in .ipa build file? if "EnablePushNotification" is not defined?

Comment: ifdef means 'if defined', so the code inside will only be processed if there is a 'define' statement for it.